# Grouping FCM Notification Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

i'm trying to achieve something like this

[image]

I'm using flutter_local_notifications: ^4.0.1+2 . Here is what i do so far

```
        BigTextStyleInformation bigTextStyleInformation =
            BigTextStyleInformation(
          payload.notification.body,
          htmlFormatBigText: true,
          contentTitle: payload.notification.title,
          htmlFormatContentTitle: true,
          summaryText: payload.data['group_name'].toString(),
          htmlFormatSummaryText: true,
        );

        AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
            AndroidNotificationDetails(
          payload.data['group_name'].toString(),
          payload.data['group_name'].toString(),
          payload.data['group_name'].toString(),
          styleInformation: bigTextStyleInformation,
          groupKey: payload.data['group_id'].toString(),
          setAsGroupSummary: true,
          importance: Importance.high,
        );
        //
        NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics =
            NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics);
        await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
            int.parse(payload.data['chat_index']),
            payload.notification.title,
            payload.notification.body,
            platformChannelSpecifics);
```

And here is what i send to fcm server

```
{
  "registration_ids": [
    "dhFLSBuAT3yYC4XoeY7oKf:APA91bGbtYTxmHhua7kewUbR1-PCHlGXyS_WP1jP-vjoLkJ_JoB69fuR8XO8hfmv-_r8VekBIkuFqhhJaHSnlKIJVRaeCAE7Mu682ffZ4MASC2O_v0QR--pQOqY3Anm7Q8liEh4Sg6f9"
  ],
  "notification": {
    "body": "Example Message",
    "title": "GROUP TEST 1",
    "icon": "@drawable/ic_stat_notification_logo",
    "sound": "mySound",
    "priority": "high",
    "show_in_foreground": true,
    "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"
  },
  "data": {
    "type": "chat",
    "openScreen": true,
    "useHomeScreen": true,
    "homeScreenBottomIndex": 1,
    "group_id": 1,
    "group_name": "GROUP 1",
    "chat_index": 1
  }
}
```

From my script above i get this result

[image]

Any solution for this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out [awesome_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications) : `0.0.6+9`

1. Using `Group Key` you can determine the common key used to group notifications in a compact form.
2. You can even use `Group Sort` to determines the notifications sort order inside the grouping

## OR

You can check out [Grouping-Notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications#grouping-notifications) of local notifications.

The following code is a "translation to flutter" of the sample available at https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/group.html

**Code -**

```
const String groupKey = 'com.android.example.WORK_EMAIL';
const String groupChannelId = 'grouped channel id';
const String groupChannelName = 'grouped channel name';
const String groupChannelDescription = 'grouped channel description';
// example based on https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/group.html
const AndroidNotificationDetails firstNotificationAndroidSpecifics =
    AndroidNotificationDetails(
        groupChannelId, groupChannelName, groupChannelDescription,
        importance: Importance.max,
        priority: Priority.high,
        groupKey: groupKey);
const NotificationDetails firstNotificationPlatformSpecifics =
    NotificationDetails(android: firstNotificationAndroidSpecifics);
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(1, 'Alex Faarborg',
    'You will not believe...', firstNotificationPlatformSpecifics);
const AndroidNotificationDetails secondNotificationAndroidSpecifics =
    AndroidNotificationDetails(
        groupChannelId, groupChannelName, groupChannelDescription,
        importance: Importance.max,
        priority: Priority.high,
        groupKey: groupKey);
const NotificationDetails secondNotificationPlatformSpecifics =
    NotificationDetails(android: secondNotificationAndroidSpecifics);
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
    2,
    'Jeff Chang',
    'Please join us to celebrate the...',
    secondNotificationPlatformSpecifics);

// Create the summary notification to support older devices that pre-date
/// Android 7.0 (API level 24).
///
/// Recommended to create this regardless as the behaviour may vary as
/// mentioned in https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/group
const List<String> lines = <String>[
    'Alex Faarborg  Check this out',
    'Jeff Chang    Launch Party'
];
const InboxStyleInformation inboxStyleInformation = InboxStyleInformation(
    lines,
    contentTitle: '2 messages',
    summaryText: 'janedoe@example.com');
const AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
    AndroidNotificationDetails(
        groupChannelId, groupChannelName, groupChannelDescription,
        styleInformation: inboxStyleInformation,
        groupKey: groupKey,
        setAsGroupSummary: true);
const NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics =
    NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics);
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
    3, 'Attention', 'Two messages', platformChannelSpecifics);
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you making sure that the `chat_index` in your payload (`payload.data.chat_index`) are **unique** between notifications in the same group. You're using this as the `id` passed to `FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show`. If they all have the same `chat_index` (ID), that might be a problem. You can also just randomly generate a number locally when the notification comes in, it doesn't need to be in the payload.

Also, you might want to upgrade to `6.0.0` since you are 2 major versions behind. There *might* have been bug fixes you could make use of, but these new releases are probably all related to null safety.